# ratchet with zmq on subdomain not connecting

Tags: sockets, websocket, ratchet, php-socket

I'm trying to run ratchet on sub domain.. i have create ratchet server as described in Ratchet push integration and uploaded it to subdomain.domain.com  my subdomain is also on same server
my projects is in laravel which is on main domain.(www.domain.com)

here is my chatserver code which is on subdomain

```
<?php
    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
    $pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

    //Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
    $context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
    $pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
    $pull->bind('tcp://subdomain.domain.com:5555'); //Binding to 27.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
    $pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onBookingSeats'));

    //Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
    $webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
    $webSock->Listen(80,'0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
    $webSock = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
        new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
            new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
                new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                    $pusher
                    )
                )
            ),
        $webSock
        );

    $loop->run();
?>
```

my controller code from where i am sending request to socket which is on www.domain.com

```
    $context = new ZMQContext();
    $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
    $socket->connect("tcp://subdomain.domain.com:5555");

    $socket->send(json_encode($seats));
    return Redirect::to('booking/payment');
```

and recieving websocket request in js file on www.domain.com

```
var conn = new ab.Session('ws://rtime.ticketpk.com:80',
    function() {
        conn.subscribe('kittensCategory', function(topic, data) {
            // This is where you would add the new article to the DOM (beyond the scope of this tutorial)
            console.log('New article published to category "' + topic + '" : ' + data.title);
        });
    },
    function() {
        console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
    },
    {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
);
```

i think i'm having problem in binding with websockets

Comment: Having same issue, found a solution anyone?